# How do I use Java to read from a file that is real life?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, reader

The reason I do use MultipartFile is because there is a button image in the image in swagger. I am successfully adding the values in the excel file I received to the database, but at the same time I am encountering the following error.

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@6417030b
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:318)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at az.expressbank.expressbankproject.service.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl.acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase2(UserDetailServiceImpl.java:62)
    at az.expressbank.expressbankproject.controller.UserDetailController.writeExcelledRowColumnIntoDatabase(UserDetailController.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But another problem, I can't send my file to the folder I specified. I think I've closed everything, but still I can't send it to the specified folder, if I send it and fix the error I explained above, my problem will no longer exist.

```
 public Response acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase2(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        if (fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 5, fileName.length()).equals(".xlsx")) {
            try (InputStream excelFile = file.getInputStream()) {
                String phoneNumber = "";
                String textMessage = "";
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile);
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.rowIterator();
                while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
                    Row currentRow = rowIt.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                        if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                            phoneNumber = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                            textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
                UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
                userDetail.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                userDetail.setTextMessage(textMessage);
                this.userDetailRepository.save(userDetail);
                excelFile.close();
                workbook.close();
                Path sourcePath = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
                Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ko\\" + sourcePath.getFileName());
                Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath);
                return new SuccessResponse(MessageCase.FILE_SUCCESSFULLY_WRITTEN_TO_DATABASE.getMessage(), 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new ErrorResponse(MessageCase.FAILED_HAPPEND_WHEN_FILE_WRITTEN_TO_DATABASE, 404);
    }
```

Comment: Is your application a web app?  if so you'll want to have the user upload the file first (https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/), then your app can decide the local file path/file name to assign to it before reading like @Lajos has indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `String path` parameter instead. Then you could do something like this:

```
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: What I don't understand is, for example, let's say in the view page section, when the user presses the add file button, what should the file  type that he sent there look like? Yani ben metodumun parametresinde tam olarak ne yazacağım, kısaca basit örnek göstere bilirmisin?

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov we are probably speaking about Excel files, so they should be xls or the like.

Comment: Yes we are, but for example I will understand if any of you can briefly show me how to do this and that with a simple example of my method.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov with all due respect, I'm convinced that my answer provides all the information you need. If you follow my instructions, then you pass a path to your method instead of a String that represents the file content. You still pass a String, but it represents the path rather than the content. Then, in your method you initialize a File object and use that to create a FileInputStream. You can test the method by passing a hard-coded path where you know you have a file. You need to follow the instructions, try them and if you find a blocker, then please specify how you failed to apply

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov the steps described here. Your comment suggests that you did not even try to follow the instructions, but rather, you expect me to be aware of some UI that you did not provide any information about whatsoever and which is apparently in your project and you have asked me to provide a simple example of your method. But what kind of example? Have you described any files that you try to use? I have no information whatsoever about your files, your UI and frankly, it is not necessary for me to be aware of those. The only important things here are as follows:

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov 1. Rename your parameter from `file` to path, 2. Move `FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);` into your `try` block, 3. Put the line of `File file = new File(path);` into the `try` block as its first line, 4. Pass an actual path to the method where you know you can find a file. If you fail to do so, don't worry, in that case you can always come back here with questions, but the purpose of these answers are to help you understand and solve your problem, we have no purpose of writing your code.

Comment: I did as you said, it didn't work. But I finally found what I wanted. What I wanted was the kind of MultipartFile interface. I did as you said, it didn't work. But I finally found what I wanted. What I wanted was the kind of MultipartFile interface. My method will receive a file of type MultipartFile in its parameter, but I could not print it to the database in my code. There is one last thing I want, what changes can I make to my method using MultipartFile?

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov I don't know how it didn't work. If you could elaborate on what and how you tried and how it failed, then I would take a look. If not, then I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov I think that if we solve the issue, then it will be useful for future visitors as well. So, let's keep the discussion here. You can edit your question with further information and you can notify me in a comment here if you want to. I'm sure that the approach I have proposed should work, so there might be a misunderstanding here. Also, if you found another solution, which works for you, then we can use that as our starting point. But I'm not sure what your further problem is. So there is a lack of information about the problem that we need to resolve first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597565/how-to-read-any-file-of-format-using-multipartfile see this question, I explained very well in this question.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov looking at it.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov even though you have chosen another approach, which may be fine, I wonder how and why this did not work for you. It might be a useful information for future users if you could share the reason why this approach did not work.

Comment: I have getting this error java.io.FileNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@43ddee71 (The system cannot

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov this is part of the stack trace. If you could add the full stack trace to the question, that would be great. At this point it seems to me that you did not use a resource, maybe `import java.io.File` would help you at the start of your file. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: again different error org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)

Comment: Actually, if you understand what I want, maybe you can help.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov `EmptyFileException` means that the file you wanted to load was empty. So you have successfully taken a step towards the solution. It seems that the path you have passed does not point to a valid file. How do you call the method when you get this error? Can you edit your question with this information?

Comment: carefully listen to me, the reason I get a value of type MultipartFile is because in swagger it sends the file by clicking the button. But when I use String instead of MultipartFile, it works without any problem, but in swagger I throw your file in array format, not keystroke, just like this: C:/Users/User/Desktop/file.xlsx. I use MultipartFile as I don't want this.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov I do not understand your scenario and why the proposed solution did not work. My view is that if you have a file somewhere on your hard drive and you know its path and you have access rights to it, then you should be able to read it in the way proposed here. If your scenario is different, then I wish you the best of luck resolving your problem.

Comment: I made changes in my code and it successfully prints the values in the excel file to the database, but at this time it gives an error, the error is this in my question updated.

Comment: I made changes some of code, in above error, which I show  org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile already I am not getting the error. This error When I move file in specified folder, how to move file in specified folder the best way?

Answer (score 0):

The issue likely is this non-sensical `targetPath` which you build up there:

```
Path sourcePath = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ko\\" + sourcePath.getFileName());
```

This might fail already:

```
assertTrue(Files.exists(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ko\\")));
```

`Files.exists(Path)` also returns `false`, when not being permitted to list the directory.

Comment: Exactly, when I put these lines in the comment line, I don't get any errors anymore, but now there is another problem, I want to put the excel file I received in a folder on my computer, how can I do that? @Martin Zeitler

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov I'm not exactly sure about SpringBoot, but it could also be that the application server does not permit file-system access outside of it's root directory and/or designated storage facilities... and it's common practice, to check if the directory exists and if it is writeable, before trying to write into it.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could help me find the related questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have successfully solved all the problems and everything is working fine.In this case, What I wanted to do was to take the excel file using MultipartFile and print the values in it to the appropriate columns in the database, and then the most difficult thing was to assign the excel file I got from the user to the folder I specified on the computer.

```
 @Override
    public Response acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase2(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(file.getContentType());
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        if (fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 5).equals(".xlsx")) {
            try (InputStream excelFile = file.getInputStream()) {
                String phoneNumber = "";
                String textMessage = "";
                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
                Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                for (Row currentRow : datatypeSheet) {
                    for (Cell currentCell : currentRow) {
                        if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                            phoneNumber = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                            textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
                UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
                userDetail.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                userDetail.setTextMessage(textMessage);
                this.userDetailRepository.save(userDetail);
                excelFile.close();

                String destination = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ko\\"  + file.getOriginalFilename();
                File file1 = new File(destination);
                file.transferTo(file1);

                return new SuccessResponse(MessageCase.FILE_SUCCESSFULLY_WRITTEN_TO_DATABASE.getMessage(), 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new ErrorResponse(MessageCase.FAILED_HAPPEND_WHEN_FILE_WRITTEN_TO_DATABASE, 404);
    }
```